# Mysql Database Not inserting value

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following insert  command to insert value in my db table called demo_organization

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo_organization (org_name, abn_acn_no, org_url,city,
                    state, country, pin, street, primary_mobile, 
                    secondary_mobile, primary_landline, 
                    secondary_landline, primary_email,  secondary_email)

            VALUES ($org_name, $abn_acn_no, $org_url, $city, $state, $country, 
                    $pin, $street, $primary_mobile, $secondary_mobile, 
                    $primary_landline, $secondary_landline, $primary_email, 
                    $secondary_email)";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

in php 
but i am getting  error like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '://loc.com,Melburn,Melburn,Australia,56007,123 park
>   avenue,+6190567890,+89685552' at line 2

i am completely new in php mysql please tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing single quotes around the text values:

```
insert into demo (org_name, abn_acn_no) values ('$org_name', abn_acn_no);
// assumes that abn_acn_no is numeric.
```

You also cannot pass an empty variable into the query. If you don't have it, you will need to insert it as `, null,` rather than as a variable with no value - which would result in `, ,` which SQL won't accept - even if the column accepts null values.

Comment: @MBJ Not inside a SQL query it won't. If you have `3, $yourVar, 3` in a query (and `$yourvar='testing'` then the query will look like `3, testing, 3` which will not be accepted by mysql as the string is not encapsulated within quotes.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO demo_organization (org_name, org_url,abn_acn_no,city,state,country,pin,street,primary_mobile,secondary_mobile,primary_landline,secondary_landline,primary_email,secondary_email)
   VALUES('$org_name','$org_url','$abn_acn_no','$city','$state','$country','$pin','$street','$primary_mobile','$secondary_mobile','$primary_landline','$secondary_landline','$primary_email','$secondary_email')";
i tried with this also but getting same error

Comment: @user1481793 You probably have an empty field. You can check it easily with `echo $sql;` before passing it to the `mysql_query` function and this will show you what you are missing. If you are missing fields, you will need to insert a `null` in their place.

Comment: thanks for ur comment i was passing an empty field now i fixed that with ur help

Comment: @user1481793 Interesting choice of Accepted answer then hehe :)

Comment: Actually your  comments help me out

Comment: @user1481793 All the more so lol as his answer has nothing to do with an empty field. Anyhow, bed time for me. Good luck and good coding.

Comment: You do not slap quotes around your strings and call it a day. This is what gets you fired when your company's database is trashed by a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using MYSQL, you need to escape the values `mysql_escape_string($string)`

There is a problem with the **url** provided in the query, try escaping it and running it again.

Otherwise, MYSQL is becoming depreciated, use MYSQLi or PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: thanks :) it seems the voted answer, isn't getting positive feedback anyway

Comment: I just try to answer MySQL questions and the PHP world seems *totally oblivious* to how to escape SQL properly. I'm just doing my part to push back against this kind of reckless behavior, and it's good to see you are too.

Answer (score 0):

your code is vulverable with your sql injection. I'll recomend **[MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**. But anyway, your values that are `string format should be wrap with single quotes`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo_organization (org_name, abn_acn_no, org_url,city,
                state, country, pin, street, primary_mobile, 
                secondary_mobile, primary_landline, 
                secondary_landline, primary_email,  secondary_email)
        VALUES ('$org_name', 'abn_acn_no, '$org_url', '$city', ...,
                 '$secondary_email')";
```

Comment: You're right to recommend `mysqli` and PDO, but since this answer is massively vulnerable to SQL injection, it is incorrect. You should be using placeholders like you suggest.